# Riesz representation theorem for $C_{0}([0,T])$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, riesz-representation-theorem

I have a question about the Riesz representation theorem.

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $C(X)$ the Banach space
of all continuous functions on X with supremum norm. The Riesz representation theorem says that every bounded linear operator on $C(X)$ is realized by an integral with respect to an certain finite signed measure on $X$

I am trying to apply this theorem for the following Banach space.

$T>0$ : fix.

$C([0,T]):=\{w:[0,T]\to \mathbb{R}\,;\, w \,{\rm is\,conti.}  \}$

$C_{0}([0,T]):=\{w \in C([0,T]) \,;  \,w(0)=0  \}$

Then $C([0,T]),C_{0}([0,T])$ is Banach space with supremum norm $\|w\|=\sup_{0 \leq t \leq T}|w(t)|$

According to the above theorem, for any $A \in C([0,T])^{*}$,  there exists an certain finite signed measure on $[0,T]$

Let $A \in C_{0}([0,T])^{*} $. Then can we deduce a finite signed measure corresponds to $A$ is a finite signed measure on $(0,T]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Apply Riesz representation theorem for the operator $$Bf := A(f-f(0)), \qquad f \in C([0,T]).$$

Comment: By Riesz representation theorem $A(f-f(0))=Bf=\int_{[0,T]}fd\mu_{B}$ Here $\mu_{B}$ is a finite signed measure on $[0,T]$ $\mu_{B}$ corresponds to $A$?

Comment: Yes... Note that $B|_{C_0}=A$.

Comment: I understand a finite signed measure corresponds to $A$ is $\mu_{B|_{C_{0}}}$. How is this connected to a finite signed measure on $(0,T]$?

Comment: @ko4 Sorry, I don't know what you mean. The measure $\mu$ satisfies $$Bf = \int f \, d\mu = Af$$ for any $f \in C_0$.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken. Thanks to you I understood.

Answer (score 1):

If $\Phi \in C_{0}[0,T]^{\star}$, then, by the Hahn-Banach Theorem, there exists $\Psi \in C[0,T]^{\star}$ such that $\|\Phi\|=\|\Psi\|$ and $\Psi=\Phi$ on $C_{0}[0,T]$. That yields the existence of a finite signed Borel measure $\mu$ on $[0,T]$ such that
$$
                  \Phi(f) = \int_{0}^{T}f\,d\mu.
$$
The measure $\mu$ is unique among the finite Borel signed measures for which $\mu\{0\}=\mu\{T\}=0$. This uniqueness follows from fact that the characteristic functions of open intervals $(a,b)\subseteq (0,T)$ are pointwise limits of uniformly bounded functions in $C_{0}[0,T]$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's a interesting solution.